# Filtering and selecting files from a directory

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser, filefilter

I have an application right now that selects files from a directory. what I want to do is be able to have a feature where you can put in a file extension such as `.gif`, `.txt` etc.. and after a button is clicked the application will run through the directory and find and select all files of that type. The only code I have to show is of my current application which has none of this. Was hoping for a point in the right direction or some advice.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung
i didn't upvote. I haven't tried anything. Not even sure how to approach it. I know how to filter files by extension but not how to have them all in one place similar to a search of your hard drive for a particular file type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private List<File> getMatchingFiles(File parent, final String extension) {
    File[] files = parent.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File dir) {
            String name = dir.getName();
            if(name.endsWith(extension)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    List<File> retval = Arrays.asList( files );
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: now I can throw this into an actionevent and just add different extensions for different file types? What I will have is a search button and when you type in .jpg, for example, then this will return all files of that type? By the way, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For use in a `JFileChooser`, all the answers so far offered are sub-optimal.  Instead implement  [`JFileChooser.setFileFilter(javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29) for the best user experience.

It might end up looking something like this<sup>1</sup>:

[image: JFileChooser with file filters]

1. Image obtained using code courtesy of [A Sample FileChooser Program](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node99.html).

Comment: +1 for most awful printscreen from dinosaurus ages :-) phaaaa brrrrr

Comment: @healix not, never, why to reinvent the wheel, here is your answer and proper ways too, why traversing in File[] ???

Comment: @mKorbel That one was courtesy of 'my mate Google'.  I was trawling for `JFileChooser+FileFilter` and looking at any image that had the list expanded, ..then I rejected one that was 40Kb (and horrible) and another (really nice one) that was 71Kb and settled for the image that was <6.5 Kb (and showed the mouse pointer).  ;)

Comment: I doubt that is made by Java ....., sorry I can't remember for windows came from Win3.21 or Win95 :-)

Comment: @mKorbel  Sure it is, but my bad, I should have linked to the source (done now).

Comment: @mKorbel: That's a vintage [Mac OS 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mac_OS#Mac_OS_8) [Java 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.2_.28December_8.2C_1998.29) screenshot. Late Cretaceous? :-)

Comment: @trashgod  I just scrolled to the bottom of the page to see `4/14/1999` - That would have been about the time of 1.1.8 & the `swing.jar`.  I'm thinking 'Devonian'.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably the [java.io.File#list(filter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29).

edit: If you want the entire file system be searched, then you need to recursively scan every direcotry:

```
public static void filter (String dirname, List<File> result) {
    try {
        for (String f : new File(dirname).list()) {
            String filename = dirname + f;
            File theFile = new File(filename);
            if (theFile.isDirectory()) {
                filter(filename + "/", result);
            } else if (new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return pathname.getName().endsWith(".gif");
                }
            }.accept(theFile)) {
                result.add(theFile);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // may raise null-pointer when access denied
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    filter("F:/", result);

    System.out.println(result.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
   return (!name.endsWith(".gif") 
    }
};
```